# ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: reactjs, windows, build, next.js, yarnpkg

I got this error when i try to start `yarn build` command.

```
Build error occurred
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder\podcastr\.next\routes-manifest.json'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\cmder\\podcastr\\.next\\routes-manifest.json'
}
```

Comment: You do realize that you have created your project inside Program Files? And that too in your terminal's directory. Create it somewhere else, or run your terminal in administrator mode. Windows doesn't allow modification of Program Files without administrative access.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not an error. Just delete your .next and node_modules folder and try to build again. It will work. This only happens in windows for some reason.